# Make picture "stick" to the border of thumbnail tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a list of employees (2 items in each row), and I've encountered several problems:

- I want picture to use full space of left side of list item - the example is here: http://2fm9xz2drvqemrbu.zippykid.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/facebook-search-results.jpg
- borders of list items with thumbnail class touches each other - I'd like to have some padding

My example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bC4Wy/

My list item code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" /></div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="h4">Paul Smith</div>
            <div>Title: Developer</div>
            <div>Skills: C#, .NET</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using thumbnail and putting "col" inside of col directly.

You may consider not using thumbnail at all:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 listitem">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="h4">Paul Smith</div>
        <div>Title: Developer</div>
        <div>Skills: C#, .NET</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listitem {
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.listitem img {margin-left: -15px;}
```

I have also added additional `row` to insure your layout will be consistent. You may want to add styling for the border radius for mozilla and webkit.